# Proof if $AB+BA=0$ Then atleast one of the matrices are singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem :

$A,B \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ matrices while $n$ odd number.

Proof if $AB+BA=0$ then atleast one of $A,B$ is singular.

I assume that $A,B$ invertible.

Its clear that $\det(AB) \neq 0$ and  $\det(BA) \neq 0$.

If I could show that, $\det(AB) \neq -\det(BA)$ then I can conclude that $\det(AB)+\det(BA) \neq 0$.

But I don't seem to find a way to show that, I guess it has something to do with $n$ odd number.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=\det(B)\det(A)=\det(BA)$ for all $A,B$. This is because multiplication of real numbers is commutative.

Comment: You seem to have a sign problem: $x\neq y$ does not imply $x+y\neq 0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, your right I forget the $-$, Edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that the determinant is completely multiplicative over square matrices, i.e., $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$. We have
\begin{align}
AB & = -BA\\
\det(AB) & = -\det(BA)\\
\det(A) \det(B) & = - \det(B) \det(A)\\
\det(A) \det(B) & = 0
\end{align}

Comment: Note: we have $\det(-M) = -\det(M)$ because $n$ is odd.  In general, $\det(kM) = k^n M$ for an arbitrary scalar $k$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, true.

Comment: @Adhvaitha Can you explain why $\det(A) \det(B) = - \det(B) \det(A)\implies
\det(A) \det(B) = 0$

Comment: @JaVaPG: Calling $a-\det(A)$ and $b=\det(B)$ (these are just numbers, so multiplication commutes for them) one has $ab=-ba\implies2ab=0\implies ab=0$ since $2\neq0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Do you mean that the determinant of BA and AB are equal since that we can conclude :
$$det(A)det(B)=−det(B)det(A)⟹2det(A)det(B)=0⟹det(A)det(B)=0?$$

Comment: @JaVaPG that is an equally valid way of arriving at the conclusion.  The key is that $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are numbers, so that
$$
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = \det(B) \det(A) = \det(BA)
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your answer, this statement $$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = \det(B) \det(A) = \det(BA)$$ is correct since we know that $n$ is odd right?

Comment: @JaVaPG no. This equality holds for every $n$.  The fact that $n$ is odd is important since $\det(-AB) = -\det(AB)$ because $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 5):

If $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ odd, then
$$\det(-C)=-\det(C)\ .$$
So for your equation,
$$\eqalign{
  AB+BA=O
  &\Rightarrow AB=-BA\cr
  &\Rightarrow \det(A)\det(B)=-\det(B)\det(A)\cr
  &\Rightarrow \det(A)\det(B)=0\cr
  &\Rightarrow \det(A)=0\ \hbox{or}\ \det(B)=0\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Can you explain how you manage to conclude $-\det(B)det(A)=0 \implies det(A)det(B)=0$

Comment: @JaVaPG: both $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are numbers, hence they commutative.

Answer (score 5):

here is a proof that does not use the determinant explicitly.

If $B$ is singular, we are done. Next suppose $B$ is nonsingular. Claim: $A$ is singular. this proves that at least one of $A$ or $B$ is singular.

Proof of the claim: $AB = -BA.$ so $A = B(-A)B^{-1},$ that is $A$ and $-A$ are similar. that means the eigenvalues must come in pairs $(\lambda, -\lambda)$ if $\lambda \neq 0.$ because the order is odd, at least one of the eigenvalues of $A$ must be zero. that proves the claim $A$ is singular.

Answer (score 0):

Determinants are just numbers and a = -a implies a = 0 for a,any number.